# Como acessar os métodos de um componente que está dentro de um arquivo do FastReport?

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Desculpem se a dúvida parecer meio confusa, mas tenho a seguinte situação:
tenho um componente frxReport e, dentro dele, inseri um gráfico no relatório.
No form principal, adicionei um radio button, que vai definir se quero o relatório com ou sem gráfico. Ai surgiu essa dúvida: como vou passar a informação obtida no form, para um componente que não está nele?
Comecei com o Delphi a pouquíssimo tempo, então, se for uma dúvida simples, relevem. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  meuMemo: TfrxMemoView;


begin

  meuMemo:= TfrxMemoView(componenteDoSeuRelatorioForm.FindComponent('meuMemo'));


  if meuMemo<> nil then

  begin

    meuMemo.text := 'teste memo';

  end;
```

`meuMemo` é o nome do componente no arquivo fr3.

`componenteDoSeuRelatorioForm` é o frxReport que você tem no seu form.

Answer (score 0):

AQUI FIZ PARA MUDAR AS CORES DO MEMO

`if FDQUERY2.FieldBYNAME('VISCERAL').Value >= 12 then
BEGIN
TfrxMemoView (frxReport1.FindObject ('Memo125')).Color := TALPhacolorRec.Orangered;
TfrxMemoView (frxReport1.FindObject ('Memo127')).Color := TALPhacolorRec.Orangered;
TfrxMemoView (frxReport1.FindObject ('Memo114')).Color := TALPhacolorRec.Orangered;
TfrxMemoView (frxReport1.FindObject ('Memo114')).font.Style :=  TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindObject('Memo114')).font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsBold];
TfrxMemoView (frxReport1.FindObject ('Memo118')).Color := TALPhacolorRec.Orangered;
TfrxMemoView (frxReport1.FindObject ('Memo118')).font.Style :=  TfrxMemoView(frxReport1.FindObject('Memo118')).font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsBold];
END;`

PARA CAPTURAR LOCAL ONDE ESTA O EXECUTÁVEL PROJETO

VARIAVEL

PATH, NOME: String;

`path := ExtractFileDir (ParamStr(0));`

NOME QUE ESTOU DANDO PARA O PREVIEW FASTREPORT

`NOME := FDQUERY2.FieldBYNAME('nome').Value +' - '+ FormatDateTime('ddmmyyyy',date);`

CHAMANDO O RELATÓRIO

`frxReport1.LoadFromFile(path+'\grafico.fr3');
frxReport1.ReportOptions.Name := 'SISTEMA EVS - AVALIAÇÃO GRÁFICA - ' + nome;
frxReport1.ShowReport;`

ESPERO AJUDAR ALGUEM COM ISSO.